# Remove different leading and training values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a field in MySQL database which contains values enclosed in (value). I want to remove the ( and ) and am trying to use TRIM.

```
SELECT field1, TRIM(both '()' FROM field1) FROM table1
```

Doesn't seem to work. While there are plenty of examples showing removing the leading and training characters which are the same, I couldn't find an example which shows how TRIM can be used to remove unlike characters. Can someone please help?

Comment: Can you add sample data for the `field1` column?

Comment: field1 = ($23.24, $55.23). I want to remove the ( and ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one option:

```
SELECT
    CASE WHEN field1 LIKE '(%)'
         THEN SUBSTRING(field1, 2, LEN(field1)-2)
         ELSE field1 END AS field1
FROM table1;
```